# How to make a wget 'alias'?

Tags: bash, ssh, alias, bioinformatics

I would like to make a command in the command prompt to easily download protein data base files by typing 'fetch ID.pdb'. The files are retrieved from www.pdb.org/pdb/files/ID.pdb.

I tried adding to .bash_profiles;

```
    alias fetch ='wget www.pdb.org/pdb/files/'
```

I thought I could then type 'fetch ID.pdb' and it would work, but it seems aliases do not work that way. Any advice? If I could retrieve the protein by typing only 'fetch ID', even better!

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using a function in your .bashrc rile

```
function fetch() {
    wget www.pdb.org/pdb/files/${1}
}
```

The alias approach does not work because the shell simply replaces the alias with the command you have set the alias to.  Thus in your question, the shell would produce: wget www.pdb.org/pdb/files/ ID.pdb.  The space, would foil wget.  Using a function lets you pass an argument that you can simply append to the URL.

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you very much EJK, I really appreciate you sharing your time.

Comment: This thing is telling me I'm not 'cool' enough to upvote yet, but I will remember and come back when I become an accepted member of society :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your alias is that you need to remove the space between the word fetch and the = symbol.  As EJK mentioned, there will be a space between your alias and the argument that you pass at the command line which will not create an appropriately formatted URL.  Spaces are special characters in the shell.

Here's another solution that eliminates the need to add the .pdb file suffix to your file ID argument so that you can just enter:

```
fetch ID
```

#### Shell Script

Create a shell script called fetch.sh that includes the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

PDB_URL="http://www.pdb.org/pdb/files/"
if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
    PDB_FILE="$1"
    wget "$PDB_URL$PDB_FILE.pdb"
else
    echo "Forgot the file ID...Try again." >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Let's say you save that on the file path ~/scripts/fetch.sh.  Run chmod on the shell script to make it executable:

```
chmod 744 ~/scripts/fetch.sh
```

#### Make an Alias for Your Shell Script

Enter the following alias in your .bashrc file:

```
alias fetch="~/scripts/fetch.sh"
```

Run a source command on the .bashrc file (with .bashrc in your working directory):

```
source .bashrc
```

And then pull your files with wget like this:

```
fetch 992532
```

using whatever ID you need.  wget will place the file in whatever working directory you are in.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Aha! Thank you. I did not know about shell scripts - that's useful to know. I appreciate it :)